# How do I install PRAW for python 2.7 (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, praw

I installed Anaconda because of pip.
Now, I'm trying to install praw.

https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/index.html#main-page

I followed the instructions in this link.

It said to install praw via pip.

```
$ pip install praw
```

However, the only thing I got was a traceback.

```
In [1]: $ pip install praw
File "(ipython-input-1-7f8077abc8e9)", line 1
$ pip install praw
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, how do I install PRAW for python 2.7 (Anaconda)?

Comment: The dollar sign represents a shell prompt (e.g. Terminal), not the Python REPL.

Comment: you install from the shell not ipython